# Translating the name of a Facebook iFrame Tab App

Tags: facebook, tabs

Does anyone know if Facebook automatically translates the iFrame Tab Application name that appears in the left hand menu on a Facebook Page?

I've added the name in English and the application language is set to English (US), but if someone in a different country visits the page then will the English name get translated automatically?

Comment: can you give me link to your app so I can try it ?

Comment: Unfortunately the application is still in production and therefore not on a publicly visible page yet. As soon as we get sign off on the UK version I'll post you the link.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook won't automatically translate your content. You can set the translations on the [Facebook Translation Manager](https://www.facebook.com/translations/) by going there and selecting your app from the drop down on the right. Then click admin panel on the left and navigate to the language you want to translate.

Answer (score -1):

Simply: NO
Facebook doesn't translate anything for you

Also if you change that Page Tab Name manually, all the previous tabs stay using the old name, as an extra information